# Error: Cannot read property 'State' of undefined

Tags: react-native, axios, react-navigation-stack

[image]
The error from the debugger and the screen

I created a blog post from local api with the aim of clicking on the "read more" button to navigate to retrieving other remaining items based on the id. However, I made use of navigation but it gave an error of "Cannot read property 'state' of undefined.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View} from 'react-native';
import Post from './components/Post';
import PostSingle from './components/PostSingle';
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';

const RootStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    PostScreen: { screen: Post},
    PostSingleScreen:{screen: PostSingle},

  }
);

const AppNavigator = createAppContainer(RootStack);
export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <AppNavigator/>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

**Post.js** 
The screen loads to POST from which a read more button is pressed to trigger PostSingle

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    ScrollView, 
    StyleSheet,
    View, 
    Text,
    InputText,
    TouchableOpacity
} from 'react-native';
import axios from 'axios';

export default class Post extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            posts: []
        }
    }
     readMore = (id) => {
         this.setState({ id: id})
         this.props.navigation.navigate('PostSingleScreen')
     } 

    componentDidMount(){
        axios.get(`http://localhost/rest_api_myblog/api/post/read.php`)
        //.then(json => console.log(json.data.data[0].id))
        .then(json => json.data.data.map(mydata =>(
            {
                title: mydata.title,
                body: mydata.body,
                author: mydata.author,
                category_name: mydata.category_name, 
                id: mydata.id 
            }
        )))
        //.then(newData => console.log(newData))
       .then(newData => this.setState({posts: newData}))
       .catch(error => alert(error))

        }

    render(){
        return (
        <View>

        <ScrollView style={styles.scrollContent}>
            <View style={styles.header}>
                <Text style={styles.headerText}>Gist Monger</Text>
            </View> 
             {   
                 this.state.posts.map((post, index) =>(
                    <View key={index} style={styles.container}>
                        <Text style={styles.display}>
                            Author:  {post.author}
                        </Text>
                        <Text style={styles.display}>
                            Category: {post.category_name}
                        </Text>
                        <Text style={styles.display}>
                            Title: {post.title}
                        </Text>
                        <Text style={{overflow:'hidden'}}>
                            Id: {post.id}
                        </Text>
                     <TouchableOpacity style={styles.buttonContainer}
                     onPress = {() => this.readMore(post.id)}
                     >
                        <Text style={styles.buttonText}>

                            Read More
                        </Text>
                     </TouchableOpacity>

                     </View> 
                 ))
             }

        </ScrollView>
            <View style={styles.footer}></View>
        </View>
        );
    }
}
```

**PostSingle.js**
The PostSingle is expected to display single post based on the id of the item clicked on the post.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    ScrollView, 
    StyleSheet,
    View, 
    Text,
    TouchableOpacity
} from 'react-native';
import axios from 'axios';

export default class Post extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            posts: []
        }
    }


    componentDidMount(){
        axios.get(`http://localhost/rest_api_myblog/api/post/read_single.php?id=${id}`)
      .then(json => json.data.data.map(mydata =>(
            {
                title: mydata.title,
                body: mydata.body,
                author: mydata.author,
                category_name: mydata.category_name, 
                body: mydata.body 
            }
        )))
       .then(newData => this.setState({posts: newData}))
       .catch(error => alert(error))

        }

    render(){
        return (
        <View>

        <ScrollView style={styles.scrollContent}>
            <View style={styles.header}>
                <Text style={styles.headerText}>Gist Monger</Text>
            </View> 
             {   
                 this.state.posts.map((post, index) =>(
                    <View key={index} style={styles.container}>
                        <Text style={styles.display}>
                            Author:  {post.author}
                        </Text>
                        <Text style={styles.display}>
                            Category: {post.category_name}
                        </Text>
                        <Text style={styles.display}>
                            Title: {post.title}
                        </Text>
                        <Text style={{overflow:'hidden'}}>
                            Body: {post.body}
                        </Text>
                     </View> 
                 ))
             }

        </ScrollView>
            <View style={styles.footer}></View>
        </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to render `< AppNavigator />` in your app.js instead of rendering <Post />. Also, in your StackNavigator you need to define `Home` key for the navigation to know which screen to show 1st.

Comment: Yes, I did that before when it was displaying error, I thought it was supposed to be Post. I have changed it back but still displaying the same error

Comment: @UmairAhmed 1. He is doing it right. 2. No you dont have to stackNavigator takes first route as initial. Payne You have to clarify where execty you are getting that error.

Comment: I think the error is coming each time I am trying to run the app. The aim is to have a button clicked then it takes me to the next page with a full view of the item displayed completely. I am designing a blog, I have title, author and category iterated on the post without the body, I want each item clicked then it displays the complete content

Comment: Does not it show the exact line?

Comment: No it doesn't show. Let me screen the error and upload in the question

Comment: Have u installed react native gesture handler along with react navigation?

Comment: Oh no I have not done that, just done now but still not navigating. More also, how do I handle the id for fetching record for a single post http://localhost/rest_api_myblog/api/post/read_single.php?id=1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188225/discussion-between-abdumutal-abdusamatov-and-payne).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to install `react-native-gesture-handler` along with `react-navigation`. See [this](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/getting-started.html)

[image]

Comment: I have added the error to the answer you provided first. If this is solved, how do I bind the id to the fetch single post from the api based on the id of the content clicked

Comment: I don't know how to use the chat